# Can I use fstab to mount ssh without pub keys and without entering a password?

Tags: mount, ssh, sshfs

I regularly have to mount a path via ssh from a server I don't have root access to. Pub key authentication is disabled and I cannot enable it and they won't enable it. Pub key authentication is no option.

But anywhere I am looking this is the only discussed option. Does it mean, there is no other way to add the password to the fstab or to some user credential file?

Thanks.

Comment: Without pub keys AND without entering a password?

Comment: Sorry I missed this. Yes exactly. Or is that way to insecure? Like connecting an smb share with an .smbcredentials file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sshfs for remote mounting using ssh with user and password 
[Ubuntu-SSHFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)

Install sshfs package

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshfs
```